# Is possible to test before Rails loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

I'm creating a gem and this gem depends Rails is loaded. I need to create a scenario when Rails is not loaded. I have this code in my gem as an example:

```rb
if defined?(Rails) && Rails.application
 #some code
end
```

I've tried to create a stub, but it seems Rails restarts the application method when we set it with nil. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fbe2433be6e052a1acac63c7faf287c52ed3c5ba/railties/lib/rails.rb#L38

```rb
Rails.stub(:application, nil) do
 # test
end
```

Comment: Apparently, you have to start Rails somehow / somewhere. What if you skip that step?

Comment: Are you trying to write a test where Rails doesn't get loaded? That is going to be tricky since your test environment needs to load in all the dependencies first. You could always have several `Gemfile` versions, one with and one without, and run two tests, one with Rails, one without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Just setup a bootstapper file for your test that does not load Rails.

```
# spec/barebones_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|

end

# optionally load your dependencies:
# Bundler.require(:some_group)
```

```
# spec/lib/mygem_spec.rb
require 'barebones_helper'
```

In fact rspec-rails already generates two separate files*:

- `spec_helper.rb` - just configures rspec.
- `rails_helper.rb` requires `spec_helper.rb` and then boots Rails through `require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)`.

Simply changing `require 'rails_helper'` to `require 'spec_helper'` will change the test to become executed outside rails.

However be aware that running the tests through Spring will generate strange results as it will keep Rails running in the background. If you're using a spring binstub you can disable spring with the DISABLE_SPRING env var.

Comment: * I don't remember the exact version where the generator was changed to generate two separate files (2.0?) but it was years and years ago.